# How to create a flip card in css with checkbox?

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a flip card using checkbox. So I created container with checkbox, and there where I want to create two forms:

```
<div class="login-container">
    <input className="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="reg-log" name="reg-log" />
    <div class="flip-card">
        <div class="flip-card-inner">
            <div class="flip-card-front">
                flip card front
            </div>
            <div class="flip-card-back">
                flip card back
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to make checkbox that if will be checked then form will change to `flip-card-back`, and when unchecked it will back to `flip-card-front`. So I added some CSS:

```
.flip-card {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-card-inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    transition: transform 0.8s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.checkbox:checked ~ .flip-card .flip-card-inner {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front {
    background-color: sandybrown;
    color: black;
}

.flip-card-back {
    background-color: sandybrown;
    color: white;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

But the line with checked doesn't work. How to achieve that with checkbox?
Any help will be appreciated. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your HTML just change the `className` property to `class`.